# Node JS RegExp memory leak / Утечка памяти с регулярками

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения

Проблема такая, делаю обычно request запрос к сайту, и через /../.match(body) парсю  данные, несколько раз. Через chromedev делаю снапшот, и обнаруживаю что в памяти весит код страницы, размноженный, который естественно занимает кучу места...

Всё перерыл, не могу ни как найти как "освободиться" эту память, ни каких ссылок ведь нет и прочего.

Данной функцией вытаскиваю данные из body, от обычного request запроса, в итоге в памяти остаются body (снапшотам проверял, весит всегда, уборщик мусора не помогает)

```
/**
 * Регулярки
 */
function extractValue(body_ext, regex_ext){
    let match = body_ext.match(regex_ext);
    return match[1];
}
```

Comment: очень интересно, но можно ваш код, который приводит к утечке?

Comment: ВОт функция извлечения данных из body, ответа от request

function extractValue(body_ext, regex_ext){
    let match = body_ext.match(regex_ext);
    return match[1];
}

Comment: в вопрос добавьте, что бы все могли увидеть)

Comment: Дописал конечно, но проблему то как решить?)

Comment: а почему вы взяли, что проблема именно в этом месте? судя по коду, тут утечки не должно быть, значит возможно в самой функции обработчике реквеста

Comment: Потому что если убрать regexp из проекта, утечки не происходит

Comment: Читал на просторах сети что якобы RegExp глобальная переменная, и при каких условиях она хранит что-то где-то)